# Rewrite URL to a PHP script with parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a service that you give it a URL like `http://myhost.com/34.png` and it will return the result of the script `http://myhost.com/create_image.php?count=34`.

I know this is possible with mod_rewrite, but I'm very new to this and I'd like some pointers on how to do this. I only want it to work for numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServerFault's [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask/214675) topic is a great start - but, more to the point, you're looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/([0-9]*)\.png$
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)\.png$ /create_image.php?count=$1 [L]
```

Line 1: Enable the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) engine (the `mod_rewrite` Apache module may need to be installed and enabled separately of this directive if it is not already active - i.e. if "RewriteEngine on" throws an error)

Line 2: If (and *only* if) the request file path begins with a leading slash and is composed of a numeric string (of arbitrary length) followed by the ".png" extension (note use of `\` character for escaping) then...

Line 3: Set the variable `$1` to the numeric string and pass the request on to the create_image.php file with the `count` parameter set accordingly then stop (`L` = last request)

I highly recommend the [AskApache `mod_rewrite` tutorials](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html) if you're just picking up `mod_rewrite` - I believe you'll find it's pretty easy to get the hang of it if you're accustomed to writing scripts.